# Trying to use drupal_http_request to get an admin page

Tags: 7

I would like to render an admin page in a popup, I thought I'd use the ctools api to render the popup and drupal_http_request to get the data for the page, however even when logged in all I get is an 'unauthorized' error. 
Looking deeper, I think there might be a way, as the function is reputed to support basic authentication, but I can't figure out how to make it work.
This is for Drupal 7.x
Or if there's a different way to render an admin page in a popup that'd be nice too. It's for a client who doesn't want to go back and forth between admin pages so the popup would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Overlay module in the core is built to do exactly this, to open admin pages in an overlay popup.  You can enable it directly from `/admin/modules`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the request was to render an admin page on a popup that takes place within the context of a different admin page. Like a popup that took place on the node edit page for example, so there would be like an option to do something on a different admin page within a popup on the node edit page itself.